# Javascript looping inside $(".variable")

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Basically, you can notice there is a problem here. I have this looping problem, how do I go about solving this? Newbie here sorry... :(

This is what I have in mind, but it seems this doesn't work :/

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      $("._"+i).each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(value);
            $("._"+i+"t").html("<b style='color:purple;'>"+sum+"</b>");
        }
      });
     };
```

---

Here is my code..

```
var sum1 = sum2 = sum3 = sum4 = sum5 = sum6 = sum7 = sum8 = sum9 = sum10 = sum11 = sum12 = 0;
       $("._1").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum1 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._1t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum1+"</b>");
        }

      });
        $("._2").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum2 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._2t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum2+"</b>");
        }

      });
         $("._3").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum3 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._3t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum3+"</b>");
        }

      });
      $("._4").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum4 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._4t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum4+"</b>");
        }

      });
       $("._5").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum5 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._5t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum5+"</b>");
        }

      });
      $("._6").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum6 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._6t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum6+"</b>");
        }

      });
      $("._7").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum7 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._7t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum7+"</b>");
        }

      });
       $("._8").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum8 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._8t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum8+"</b>");
        }

      });
       $("._9").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum9 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._9t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum9+"</b>");
        }

      });
       $("._10").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum10 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._10t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum10+"</b>");
        }

      });
        $("._11").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum11 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._11t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum11+"</b>");
        }

      });
         $("._12").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
            sum12 += parseFloat(value);
            $("._12t").html("<b style='color:blue;'>"+sum12+"</b>");
        }

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
  var sum = 0;
  $("._" + i).each(function() {
    var value = $(this).text();

    if (!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(value);
      $("._" + i + "t").html("<b style='color:purple;'>" + sum + "</b>");
    }
  });
};
```